# How to turn Product List in WooCommerce to landscape?

Tags: css, wordpress

How can I turn our product list into landscape orientation? It doesn't seem to look good when our product list is on portrait. There's a lot of white space. Would really like to fix this. Here's a link to the site: http://aom.sg/product-category/air/airdisinfect/ Thank you for your help! TT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a CSS matter. There's a style on your page that just needs an `!important` tag to override the width of the product item. Change it to this:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Here's how it'll look like:
[image]

To make sure it doesn't affect the other pages, you might want to wrap the whole content of this page in a div and add that to the CSS selector like this:

```
<div class="products-wrapper">
    <ul class="products">
        <!-- product list -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then on your CSS:

```
.woocommerce .products-wrapper ul.products li.product,
.woocommerce-page products-wrapper ul.products li.product {
    width: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: IT WORKED! Thanks a lot! <3

Comment: Anytime! I suggest you change the tags to this question so it's categorized correctly to CSS than the existing ones. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, it worked with the product list but the product category photo thumbnail became too big? TT http://aom.sg/product-category/air/

Comment: Might be cache? Doesn't seem big to me

Comment: Edited my answer, edit your HTML and wrap your list so it doesn't affect the other pages with the same structure. You might wanna checkout woocommerce templating structure for this. Good luck! :)

Comment: Hi! Sorry I wasn't able to check your comment regarding div class. I'm actually new to this and don't have much background in coding. Where should I put this code? <div class="products-wrapper">
    <ul class="products">
        <!-- product list -->
    </ul>
</div>

Comment: Alright! Thanks Suika. Really appreciate the help! <3